hamburger menu is not showing up, any idea
I made span lines to use for the burger menu but they dont show up. If I write something inside then the letters show up but nothing before hand. the code also does not seem to respond to the padding or margin so my page is stuck to the upper right. Any ideas? Could it be my browser? When I go live I get an error reading my broswer needs an update and it cannot find the javascript but I did as directed and update the broswer as well.
    <style>
        .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
        .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header class="header">
        <nav class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
          <a href="/" class="header__logo">
            <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="Easybank logo">
          </a>

          <a href="#" class="header__menu">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </header>




    ///stylesheet 

    .header {

      &__logo {

        img {

        }

     }



      &__menu {//burger menu

        > span {
            display: block;
            width: 26px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: $darkBlue;

            &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            }
          }
        }
    }


W3C CSS/JS hamburger menu  Is that react?  Scrap the framework, you don't need it.  You don't have to use JS at all, honestly.
